# Create xml with php

Tags: php, xml

I have this PHP script from a file uploader. It is generating a XML file, but every-time I upload a new item it replaces the current nodes instead of adding to the "tree".

```
<?php

$todayDate = $_POST['todayDate'];
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];    
$filetmpname = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"];
$fileSizeMB = ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] / 1024 / 1000);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "images/".$filename);



$xml = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument( '1.0' , 'iso-8859-1' );
$xml->startElement("galeria");
$xml->writeElement("Name", $Name);
$xml->writeElement("Email", $Email);
$xml->endElement();

$file = fopen('data.xml','w+');
fwrite($file, $xml->outputMemory(true));
fclose($file);
```

Comment: The XMLWriter documentation should tell you how to do this.

Comment: why not use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) ?

Comment: try $file = fopen('data.xml', 'a');  I think that is the correct way to append a file.

Comment: @Jim: Yep.  `'w'` (or `'w+'`) truncates the file, `'a'` (or `'a+'`) appends.

Comment: Thank you! it is looking better now, but now it appends everything (including the '1.0' , 'iso-8859-1'..Onde again, thank you, it is the first time I use php, but I really need to do this!

Comment: Your problem is that you can not just concatenate two XML files/documents to get the larger one. Instead you need to learn about how to concatenate two XML documents, which should be clear to you in the first place otherwise I suggest to learn about XML first.

Answer (score 2):

try `$file = fopen('data.xml', 'a');` I think that is the correct way to append a file